# Custom boolean text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If in my BusinessStore model/table I have the boolean:

```
create_table :business_stores do |t|
    t.boolean :online_store
end
```

And in my view I wanted it to say "Online" instead of true or false as a string:

```
<% @business_stores.each do |business_store| %>
    <%= business_store.online_store %>
<% end %>
```

How would it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% @business_stores.each do |business_store| %>
    <%= "Online" if business_store.online_store %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5):

I go by the rule to keep the logic out of views, so I would create a method in the BusinessStore model:

```
def BusinessStore < ActiveRecord::Base
    def status
       if online_store
         "Online"
       else
         "Some other type or blank"
       end
    end
end
```

Then in the view

```
<%= business_store.status %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe so:

```
<%= business_store.online_store ? "Online" : "Offline" %>
```

?